# Removing from hash table

Tags: linked-list, hashtable

I have remove() function in linked list used by erase() in hash table for removing. But it doesn't work correctly in comparison to work of stl's erase(). Because of it, as I assume, find() doesn't work correctly easier(I tried the same code but without erase() and both insert() and find() were done right).

As console output is:

**My HashTable: Time: 0.610612, after insert: 315847, after erase: 164421, found: 0

STL unordered_map: Time: 0.67032, after insert: 315847, after erase: 116178, found: 116028

:(**

```
bool remove(long long key) {
    if (head == nullptr) { // If list is empty
        return false;
    }
    if (head->key == key) { //is head
        HashNode* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (head) {
            head->prev = nullptr;
        } else {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    HashNode* current = head;
    while (current != nullptr && current->key != key) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == nullptr) { // If key not found
        return false;
    }
    if (current == tail) { // is tail
        HashNode* temp = tail;
        tail = tail->prev;
        if (tail) {
            tail->next = nullptr;
        } else {
            head = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    } else {
        HashNode* temp = current;
        current->prev->next = current->next;
        current->next->prev = current->prev;
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's the erase():

```
bool erase(long long key) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(key);
    bool found = bucketsArray[bucketIndex].remove(key);
    
    if (found) {
        uniqueKeyCount--;
        float loadFactor = (float)uniqueKeyCount / bucketCount;
        if (loadFactor < MAX_LOAD_FACTOR / 2) {
            rehash();
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

I'm not sure where exactly is the problem, as there are no problems in compiler/debugger. I'd very thankful if you could help me with this.

Here's the whole code with the test function which checks if everything is ok:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
const int M = 10000;
const double MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75;




long long generateRandLong() {
    int numDigits = rand() % 19 + 10; // Random number of digits between 10 and 19
    unsigned long long num = rand() % 9 + 1; // Random non-zero first digit
    for (int i = 1; i < numDigits; i++) {
        unsigned long long digit = rand() % 10;
        num = num * 10 + digit;
    }
    return num % (unsigned long long)(pow(10, 18));
}


string generateRandColor() {
    string colors[] = { "black", "white", "gold", "rose gold", "silver" };
    return colors[rand() % 5];
}

struct Data {
    long long number;
    string color;
    bool is_charger;

    Data() {
        number = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        color = generateRandColor();
        is_charger = rand() % 2;
    }
};

struct HashNode {
    long long key;
    Data data;
    HashNode* next;
    HashNode* prev; //doubly

    // constructor
    HashNode(Data data) {
        this->data = data;
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
}

    HashNode(long long k, Data v) : key(k), data(v), next(nullptr) {}
};

struct LinkedList {
    HashNode* head = nullptr;
    HashNode* tail = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
    
    ~LinkedList() {
        clear();
    }
    
void push_front(HashNode* newHashNode) { 
    newHashNode->prev = newHashNode->next = nullptr;
    if (head == nullptr) {
        tail = head = newHashNode;
    }else{
        newHashNode->next = head;
        head->prev = newHashNode;
        head = newHashNode;
    }
    size++;
}

    HashNode* getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    
    void clear() {
        HashNode* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    
bool remove(long long key) {
    if (!head) { // If list is empty
        return false;
    }
    if (head->key == key) { // If node to remove is head
        HashNode* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (head) {
            head->prev = nullptr;
        } else {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    HashNode* current = head;
    while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->key != key) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current->next == nullptr) { // If key not found
        return false;
    }
    if (current->next == tail) { // If node to remove is tail
        HashNode* temp = tail;
        tail = current;
        current->next = nullptr;  // Update the current tail node's next pointer
        if (tail->prev) {
            tail->prev->next = nullptr; // Set the next pointer of the previous node to null
        } else {
            head = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    } else {
        HashNode* temp = current->next;
        current->next = current->next->next;
        if (current->next) {
            current->next->prev = current; // Update the previous pointer of the next node
        } else {
            tail = current; // Update tail to the current node
        }
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
}

bool search(long long key) {
    HashNode* current = head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->key == key) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}


};


struct HashTable {

    LinkedList* bucketsArray;
    int bucketCount;
    bool isEmpty = true;
    int uniqueKeyCount = 0;
    float MAX_LOAD_FACTOR;

    // Hash function for long long keys
    int hash(long long key) {
        return key % bucketCount;
    }

    HashTable(int initialBucketCount, float MAX_LOAD_FACTOR) {
        bucketCount = initialBucketCount;
        this->MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = MAX_LOAD_FACTOR;
        bucketsArray = new LinkedList[bucketCount];
    }

    ~HashTable() {
        delete[] bucketsArray;
    }


void rehash() {
    int oldBucketCount = bucketCount;
    bucketCount *= 2;
    LinkedList* newBucketsArray = new LinkedList[bucketCount];
    uniqueKeyCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldBucketCount; i++) {
        HashNode* current = bucketsArray[i].getHead();
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* newNode = new HashNode(current->data);
            int bucketIndex = hash(current->key);
            newBucketsArray[bucketIndex].push_front(newNode);
            uniqueKeyCount++;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    delete[] bucketsArray;
    bucketsArray = newBucketsArray;
}

void insert(long long key, Data value) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(key);
    HashNode* current = bucketsArray[bucketIndex].getHead();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->key == key) {
            current->data = value;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    HashNode* newHashNode = new HashNode(key, value);
    bucketsArray[bucketIndex].push_front(newHashNode);
    uniqueKeyCount++;

    double loadFactor = (double)uniqueKeyCount / bucketCount;
    if (loadFactor > MAX_LOAD_FACTOR) {
        rehash();
    }
}
    
bool erase(long long key) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(key);
    bool found = bucketsArray[bucketIndex].remove(key);
    
    if (found) {
        uniqueKeyCount--;
        float loadFactor = (float)uniqueKeyCount / bucketCount;
        if (loadFactor < MAX_LOAD_FACTOR / 2) {
            rehash();
        }
    }
    return found;
}


    bool find(long long key) {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key);
        return bucketsArray[bucketIndex].search(key);
    }

    int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++) {
            LinkedList& bucket = bucketsArray[i];
            HashNode* current = bucket.getHead();
            while (current != nullptr) {
                count++;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

};

bool testHashTable()
{
    const int iters = 500000;
    const int keysAmount = iters * 1;

    // generate random keys:
    long long* keys = new long long[keysAmount];

    long long* keysToInsert = new long long[iters];
    long long* keysToErase = new long long[iters];
    long long* keysToFind = new long long[iters];

    for (int i = 0; i < keysAmount; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = generateRandLong();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        keysToInsert[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
        keysToErase[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
        keysToFind[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
    }

    // test my HashTable:
    HashTable hashTable(500000, 0.75);

    clock_t myStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        hashTable.insert(keysToInsert[i], Data());
    }
    int myInsertSize = hashTable.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        hashTable.erase(keysToErase[i]);
    }
    int myEraseSize = hashTable.size();
    int myFoundAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        if (hashTable.find(keysToFind[i]) != NULL)
        {
            myFoundAmount++;
        }
    }
    clock_t myEnd = clock();
    float myTime = (float(myEnd - myStart)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // test STL hash table:
    unordered_map<long long, Data> unorderedMap;

    clock_t stlStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        unorderedMap.insert({keysToInsert[i], Data()});
    }
    int stlInsertSize = unorderedMap.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        unorderedMap.erase(keysToErase[i]);
    }
    int stlEraseSize = unorderedMap.size();
    int stlFoundAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        if (unorderedMap.find(keysToFind[i]) != unorderedMap.end())
        {
            stlFoundAmount++;
        }
    }
    clock_t stlEnd = clock();
    float stlTime = (float(stlEnd - stlStart)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "My HashTable:" << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << myTime << ", after insert: " << myInsertSize << ", after erase: " << myEraseSize << ", found: " << myFoundAmount << endl;
    cout << "STL unordered_map:" << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << stlTime << ", after insert: " << stlInsertSize << ", after erase: " << stlEraseSize << ", found: " << stlFoundAmount << endl << endl;

    delete[] keys;
    delete[] keysToInsert;
    delete[] keysToErase;
    delete[] keysToFind;

    if (myInsertSize == stlInsertSize && myEraseSize == stlEraseSize && myFoundAmount == stlFoundAmount)
    {
        cout << "The lab is completed" << endl;
        return true;
    }

    cerr << ":(" << endl;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    testHashTable();
}
```